What is the meaning of "Valid App Check token" when it's generated with "Firebase AppCheck with Play Integrity on Android"?

Verified requests are those that have a valid App Check token. After
you enable App Check enforcement, only requests in this category will
succeed.

What is the meaning of "valid App Check token"? By reading the App Check page and the Play Integrity page, I couldn't be sure what App Check enforcement on Firebase Services, like Cloud Run Functions, Cloud Firestore, etc, verify on.
For example, from the Play Integrity page, I could interpret that it verifies at least that the App is using the genuine binary, installed by Google Play and it's running on a genuine Android device. As well, through this API it's possible to opt-in to additional information, regarding number of requests made on, app access risk verdict and Play protect verdict.

Your app interacts with the provider of your choice to obtain an
attestation of the app or device's authenticity (or both, depending on
the provider).

Putting together those docs with the App Check Page - How does it work?, I concluded that Cloud Run Functions with enforcement turned on will then attest that any requests coming from the App have: genuine binary, installed by Google Play and it's running on a genuine Android device. But I'm not really sure about it.
